# Pictures On The Wall

Tags: visual

My friend has these pictures up on the wall. What do you think he's crazy about?

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]
[image: Third image]
[image: Fourth image]

(These pictures have a common link, and the correct answer will explain each image in the same way.)

**HINT:**
The title is also a clue.

Comment: Is it Jon Snow. 1st pic - Ghost 2nd pic - Commander (Franklin was president) , 3rd and 4th pic - Night's Watch. (Just a wildling guess)

Comment: Is your friend a shadow junkie?

Comment: @dmg: no, he isn't.

Comment: I realize this is too broad right now, so I'll reveal one hint earlier than I had planned to.

Comment: Your friend is crazy about having random pictures on his wall.

Comment: Ouch, how didn't I see this question this morning? I would have answered in 0.000001 seconds D:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh well, to me, your friend is almost surely

> a devoted Pink Floyd fan (and how could he not?)

The images represent

> Pink Floyd songs: Dogs, Money, Eclipse, Time.

And the title, well,

> the album The Wall

Also, about the description: I would say that

> 'crazy' could go very well with "Shine On You Crazy Diamond" in particular, and with a good half of their discography in general.

Comment: Great job! There's one more song reference in the description before the pictures. Think you can find it?

Comment: Right, I just added a possible explanation for that

Comment: Spectacularly done!

Comment: If these are indeed the intended theme and answers, you need a different pic for the 3rd answer -- a crescent moon at night specifically indicates that there is no [intended 3rd answer].

Comment: There is another song that relates to one of the images.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's already answered, I was convinced that the answer was something along the lines of

> Things that go away and then come back

1st

> Dogs play fetch (go out and come back)

2nd

> There is a rubber band on the bill (stretches out then snaps back)

3rd

> The moon goes up then back down every day

4th

> This is the one that makes it kind of a stretch, but the watch hands go up and back down

Comment: +1, good thinking. You were able to use one line to explain the idea, and the watch stretch isn't all that far-fetched too.

Comment: For number 2, I thought it would be "spend money to make money".

Answer (score 2):

Seems a bit obvious, but maybe he's crazy about

> dogs.

Picture 1:

> **running dogs**.

Picture 2:

> a 100-dollar bill is called a C-note, so C-dogs or **seadogs**.

Picture 3:

> **moondogs**.

Picture 4:

> **watchdogs**.

Comment: No, it's much more straightforward than that. C-Note is a not so straightforward arc to reach seadogs.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Running/a run

Because:

> Two dogs running, money run the world (or not running out of money), a moon running low (yes, there is such a thing, if it is high it is "riding high"), and time is running out (we have like less than 30 minutes till noon/midnight).

Comment: Interesting, but you missed the last line. You don't need to make up different explanations for each picture. There is one line that can sufficiently explain all pictures.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I assumed "running" explains each image.

Comment: Not without your explanation of how money runs the world, moon runs low, time runs out. Here, run has a different interpretation in each case.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Golden, could also "explain" each image. Are you looking for a full sentence?

Comment: Yes, one sentence/phrase that fits all.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that the objects are:

> Dogs (from Animals) or Dogs of war (from A momentary lapse of reason), Money, The dark side of the moon, and Time.

We notice that they are:

> All Pink Floyd songs.

Also:

> Your friend posted them on a Wall (The Wall).

So:

> Your friend likes Pink Floyd.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Good work with drawing the connection between the images, but unfortunately, [someone else got there first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16975/30903). But while you're here, why don't you just quickly take [the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)? I'm just going to edit your post so that not everything is in one spoiler, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: sure, no problem, this is my first time in this community...